# why google app engine doesn't delete my version?

Tags: google-app-engine, console, version

I have a problem deleting app engine version. 
In my Google app engine console, under the section "app engine"->"Version" I have different version of the same project. I delete one of these, i.e. *test.myapp.appspot.com*. and I can't see this version anymore in the list of the versions.
But if I try to make a call to an API of this version I have a response like this is still alive.

How can I completely delete this version? Like I never deploy it...

Comment: app version != API version. What do you mean by "API version"? How exactly do you make that API call? (and flex or standard env?)

Comment: It doesn't care about API. The problem is that it seems there is a version of my app deployed in google app engine but I can't see this version in my console. I'm worried about resources consumption in GAE.
There can be this problem?

Comment: Again, how **exactly** are you making that API call? How did you reach the conclusion that it's the deleted version that answers? Without such info there's only quesswork, which is not what stack overflow is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App Engine automatically redirects to the default version if the version you're navigating to isn't known (or has been deleted).

E.g.

If you're default version is:

```
https://1-0-0-dot-yourapp.appspot.com/
```

And you navigate to:

```
https://foo-dot-yourapp.appspot.com/
```

It'll automatically load the default version of the app (and not render a 500 error), despite the url showing  `https://foo-dot-yourapp.appspot.com/`

Comment: Ok, thanks. So foo-dot exists like a "virtual url", but the request is redirect to 1-0-0-dot

Comment: Yes, I believe so. You can test this by trying to navigate to an obvious difference between the deleted version and the default version.